# Pass a c++ object as a pointer an reuse in another function in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Suppose a I have the following 2 functions in C++:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP foo() {

  int a = 1;

  Rcpp::XPtr<int> ptr(&a, true);

  return ptr;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int bar(SEXP a){

  Rcpp::XPtr<int> x(a);
  int b = *x;

  return b;
}
```

I want to be able to call something like the following in R. 
Of course, in this example I could return an `int` to R in `foo`, but in my original code, `a` is a somewhat complex data structure and I wan't to return only the pointer to this, so it can be reused by another C++ function called `bar`

```
a <- foo()
bar(a)
```

In this example I expected that `bar(a)` returned 1 instead of 0. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your initial variable `a` goes out of scope as soon as the function finishes in `foo`.  Instead you need to initialize your pointer first, assign it, then wrap it with the `XPtr`.  The following shows an example of how to do this.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP foo() {

  int *a = new int(1);

  Rcpp::XPtr<int> ptr(a);

  return ptr;
}
```

R code

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp('test.cpp')

a <- foo()
bar(a)
[1] 1
```

Comment: Nice.  Though technically it also shows a leak as you never dispose of `a`. :)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I thought `XPtr` registers a finalizer to delete the object?

Comment: Just checked, and you are correct.  Nice feature to have :)