# Issue: return c-style pointer from an Rcpp function

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm studying Rcpp and encountered an interesting but (might be) weird issue.

Essentially `int *a = new int(1);` is not working in the same way as:

```
  int b = 1;
  int *a;
  a = &b;
```

Any ideas why? Full code below. If I uncomment `int *a = new int(1);` then the code below works as intended.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int bar(SEXP a) {
  Rcpp::XPtr<int> ptr(a);
  int b = *ptr;

  cout << b;
  return (b);
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP foo() {
  // int *a = new int(1);

  int b = 1;
  int *a;
  a = &b;

  cout << *a;
  Rcpp::XPtr<int> ptr(a);
  return ptr;
}
```

Then in R: I was hoping to get `b = 1`.

```
> a = foo()
1
> b = bar(a)
0
> b
[1] 0
```

===========================================================================
Edit: 
My question actually originates from [Pass a c++ object as a pointer an reuse in another function in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947880/pass-a-c-object-as-a-pointer-an-reuse-in-another-function-in-rcpp), but when I wish to test c-style pointer below

```
  int b = 1;
  int *a;
  a = &b;
```

to replace `int *a = new int(1);`, it's simply not working as intended. That's why I asked this question here.

Comment: It's not working the same since one is a pointer to a heap allocated int and the other is a pointer to a int on the stack. Very different things. Especially when it comes to cleanup/deleting that int. One needs an explicit `delete` the other just goes out of scope and is destroyed (and the pointer to it is now garbage).

Comment: The `.Call()` interface to R only allows `SEXP` types; see the R documentation as well as the Rcpp documentation for copious details.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks Jesper. I guess this is precisely the reason. without `new`, variables are in stack, which is then deleted once the function is finished in R-counterpart. Hence the pointer actually points to the default value 0, not 1...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks Dirk. Just had a look at R's API to C. If I wish to use c-style pointers, do I have to use PROTECT, otherwise R's garbage collector will delete them? BTW I don't think this question is duplicated though, the old question doesn't answer why c-style pointer can't be used

Comment: You _could_ use the still-existing-but-discouraged `.C()` interface.  Note that that pretty much precludes use of Rcpp.   Also note that you _can_ get a C-style pointer from a C++ object, ie `&(x[0])` is the beginning the `std::vector<T>` object.  These are all elementary C/C++ question.  There is nothing new or worthwhile for Rcpp here, really.

Comment: There is no "default 0 value". An uninitialised variable has an *indeterminate* value.

Comment: @JesperJuhl So returning 0 might be an undefined behaviour then...

Comment: @Min - Yes. It might be.